# Is my understanding of big-O correct for these Java functions incorrect?

Tags: performance, loops, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

My approach (might be incorrect) is formulaic. If there is a loop then (n+1) if there is a nested loop (n^2) if a statement then O(1). If division then log(n).

Here are some example and my reasoning to solving, not sure at all if this approach is problematic or if any of them are correct. I need help with this.

Example1:

```
i = n; // I think O(1) because it's a statment
while (i > 1) // I think O(n) because it's a loop
  i = i/4; // O(n) because it's in a loop and log_4(n) b/c division
// I think Overall if we combine the O(n) from earlier and the log_4(n)
// Therefore, I think overall O(nlog(n))
```

Example2:

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i = i + i) //  I think this is O(n+1) thus, O(n)
  System.out.println("Hello World"); // O(n) because it's in a loop
// Therefore, overall I think O(n)
```

Example3:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) // I think O(n+1), thus O(n)
  for (j = 1; j < n; j++) // I think O(n^2) because in a nested loop
    System.out.println("Hello Universe!"); // O(n^2) because in a nested
  // Therefore, overall I think O(n^2)
```

Example4:

```
for (i = 1; i < (n * n + 3 * n + 17) / 4; i = i + 1) // O((20+n^3)/4) thus, O(n^3)
  System.out.println("Hello Again!'); // O(n) because it's in a loop
// Therefore, overall I think O(n^3) because largest Big-O in the code
```

Thank you

Comment: Check how many iterations each loop does, and compare that against the value of `n` (maybe make a table if you're a visual learner). Looking at the relationship between those 2 numbers should give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Example1: Your result is wrong. Because the loop happens log_4(n) times and also the division takes O(1) (division by 4 just needs a bitwise shift). Thus the overall time is only O(log(n))

Example2: It's wrong too. In each iteration you duplicate the loop variable. So the loop happens O(log(n)) times. The print command takes O(1) and total time is O(log(n)).

Example3: Your answer is correct. Because you have two nested O(n) loops. Note that this loop is different from two previous examples.

Example4: I think you made a writing mistake. Does ((n * n + 3 * n + 17) / 4) equal O((20+n^3)/4)??? It is O(n^2). Thus, according to my previous explanations, the overall time is O(n^2).